# SBS2011 (MS Exchange 2010) Adding a message rule

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Not sure sure where this question falls, or even if it's possible.

I'm looking to add a message rule to an Exchange 2010 server (SBS2011).

Client would like every Invoice e-mail sent from their software (which generates an Outlook message on the Local machine) to be CC'd/Bcc'd to a second (internal accounts) contact (which I'm then  routing externally).

Before throwing this at the software dev's I wanted to see if there was such a thing as 'Rules' within Exchange?

Something like 'IF message sent has attachment Invoice.pdf then copy to:'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can create a Transport rule in Exchange to do this. In the EMC go to Organization Configuration|Hub Transport|Transport Rules and create a rule for this.